# Undefined method on class method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am have an app where users post. I have a filter that will order and retrieve different posts based on a value passed through the params[] hash. I keep getting a no method error on a class method that clearly exists. Here is the query I am trying to run (**posts_controller.rb**):

```
def room
    select_filter = params[:post_filter]
    course_id = params[:id].to_i

    @posts = Post.where_filter(select_filter, course_id).order_filter(select_filter).page(params[:page])    
end
```

I am getting this error whenever 'select_filter' has a value of 3 :

```
undefined method `order_filter' for #<Array:0x007fa012d6eef8>
```

Here is my model (**post.rb**, remember whenever 'select_filter' is 3 I get an error):

```
  def self.where_filter(select_filter, course_id_params)
      case select_filter.to_i
      when 1
        where('course_id = ?', course_id_params)
      when 2
        where('course_id = ?', course_id_params)
      when 3
        where('course_id = ? AND created_at > ?', course_id_params.to_i, 48.hours.ago.utc.to_s(:db))
        .reject! {|i| i.net_reputation <= 0 }
      else
        where('course_id = ?', course_id_params)
      end
    end

  def self.order_filter(select_filter)
      case select_filter.to_i
      when 1
        order('created_at DESC')
      when 2
        sort_by {|i| i.net_reputation}
      when 3
        sort_by {|i| i.net_reputation}
      else
        order('created_at DESC')
      end
  end
```

The strange thing is if I run this in the console, everything is fine. Like this:

```
Post.where('course_id = ? AND created_at > ?', 10, 48.hours.ago.utc.to_s(:db)).reject {|i| i.net_reputation <= 0 }.sort_by {|i| i.net_reputation}
```

Any and all input is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It's because your "where_filter" method is changing it from an active record relation object to an array when it gets to:

```
.reject! {|i| i.net_reputation <= 0 }
```

Once this happens, you can no longer chain other query methods onto it. Why not just make the "i.net_reputation <= 0" part of the where query?

Comment: I cannot add it to the query b/c 'net_reputation' is not a column. It is an object method that returns a calculated value. Any ideas on how to apply a method like that to the query?

Comment: How complex is the calculated value? You could always do the calculation in the database.

Comment: I mean, its kind of complicated. Basically, every post can be upvoted or downvoted. I have a table that keeps tracks of votes. what 'net_reputation' method does is it loops through all the votes associated with a post and determines the 'net' vote count (in other words, total upvotes minus total downvotes.

Comment: You may want to consider caching that calculated value in the database so you can query against it. There really isn't a way to do what you want and still retain the ability to still chain query methods.

Comment: The thing that confuses me is that if I chain all these methods together in the console, it works just fine - like so: `Post.where('course_id = ? AND created_at > ?', 10, 48.hours.ago.utc.to_s(:db)).reject {|i| i.net_reputation <= 0 }.sort_by {|i| i.net_reputation}
`

Comment: [reject](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-reject) returns an array and [sort_by](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) is available via the Enumerable module which makes it available to arrays. Your other example that is failing is trying to call 'order_filter' on a regular array.

Comment: For some reason, when I collapsed the query into one Class method, it worked. I post the solution. Thanks for your help man.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, when I collapsed the queries & sorts into one Class method, it worked. However, since Kiminari (which I am using for pagination) cannot pagniate arrays by default, I have to use the `Kaminari.pageinate_array()` method.

My posts_controller.rb:

```
def room
    @course = Course.find(params[:id])
    select_filter = params[:post_filter]
    course_id = params[:id].to_i

    query_posts = Post.select_input_filter(select_filter, course_id)
    @posts = Kaminari.paginate_array(query_posts).page(params[:page])
end
```

My post.rb:

```
def self.select_input_filter(select_filter, course_id_params)
    case select_filter.to_i
    when 1
      where('course_id = ?', course_id_params)
      .order('created_at DESC')
    when 2
      where('course_id = ?', course_id_params)
      .sort_by {|i| i.net_reputation}
      .reverse
    when 3
      where('course_id = ? AND created_at > ?', course_id_params.to_i, 48.hours.ago.utc.to_s(:db))
      .reject! {|i| i.net_reputation <= 0 }
      .sort_by {|i| i.net_reputation}
      .reverse
    else
      where('course_id = ?', course_id_params)
      .order('created_at DESC')
    end
end
```